# The instance member 'name' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Tags: string, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I always get this error when I use the String "name" to locate my Firestore docs. I don't understand why this is happening bc when I use "user.uid" it just works.

> The instance member 'name' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

This is my code:

```
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

class Folder extends StatelessWidget {
  Folder(this.name, {super.key});

  final String name;

  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> items = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection('Folder')
      .doc(name)
      .collection('Items')
      .snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        // Title
        Text(name, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall),
        // List with Items
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: items,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            final data = snapshot.requireData;

            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data.size,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(data.docs[index]['name']),
                    onTap: () {},
                  );
                },
              );
            }

            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text("error");
            }

            return const Text("error");
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And I pass the String from this StreamBuilder:

```
          stream: folder,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            final data = snapshot.requireData;

            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }

            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(00.0),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100, top: 20),
                  itemCount: data.size,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Folder(
                      data.docs[index]["name"].toString()
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            }

            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a `late` modifier to the `items` variable. Like this:

```dart
  late final Stream<QuerySnapshot> items = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection('Folder')
      .doc(name)
      .collection('Items')
      .snapshots();
```

To explain why this works: basically you can't use any instance variables when initializing other instance variables because they are all initialized when the class gets instantiated. When you add the `late` modifier, the variable will only be initialized when it's first used, meaning all the non-late variables will already be initialized.